# Example of pseudodifferential operators that smooth out the singularity of delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, microlocal-analysis

What is one example of pseudodifferential operator $P$ that smooth out the singularity of delta function, i.e. $P$ s.t. $P \delta(x) \in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{R})$?

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of the delta distribution is a constant function. Thus, if you Fourier transform, multiply with a Schwartz function and Fourier transform back, you get a Schwartz function.